# How do I bind an array of NSObjects to a UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am very new to Objective-C and Xcode and was hoping somebody might be able to give me a little assistance with a basic programming issue.

I am looking to add **TranslationRegions** (a custom data model) to a stack and call it for use within a controller.

**The array should be:**

1. Loaded when the app starts
2. Available to call at any time, anywhere in the application

Eventually, array items will be loaded via a call to a web service, but for now I'd like to load items in my model via code.

I have created an object (TranslationRegion) with .h and .m files, which I wish to use to bind a table with.

I may be going massively wrong here so any advice will be appreciated.

Translation region currently only has one property descriptionOfRegion.

I have included my controller first, to show what I'm trying to do, followed by my .h and .m files for my model.

## Actual Controller

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Regions"])
        {
            // Need to instantiate the array in here and pass it to the 'setRegions' within the Table View Controller
            //[segue.destinationViewController setRegions:regionArray];
        }
    }
```

## Table View Controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyApp Regions";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the region cell
id region = [self.regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [@"" stringByAppendingString:[TranslationRegion descriptionOfRegion:region]];

return cell;
}
```

## TranslationRegion.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TranslationRegion : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) id region;

+ (NSString *)descriptionOfRegion:(id)region;

@end
```

## TranslationRegion.m

```
#import "TranslationRegion.h"

@interface TranslationRegion()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *regionStack;
@end

@implementation TranslationRegion

@synthesize regionStack = _regionStack;

- (NSMutableArray *)regionStack
{
    if (_regionStack == nil) _regionStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _regionStack;
}

- (id)region
{
    return [self.regionStack copy];
}

+ (NSString *)descriptionOfRegion:(id)region
{
    return @"This value";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table view controller needs to implement at least

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and possibly

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

as well, so the table view knows how many cells to ask for.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I just included a snippet of my controller for brevity. It isn't throwing any errors. I'm just not 100% how to instantiate the array and add some sample content. Are you able to give me an example of how to do this in here? - if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Regions"])
            {
                //[segue.destinationViewController setRegions:regionArray];
            }, where regionArray contains a TranslationRegion stack filled with data. Excuse the beginners question but I'm stumped on this! Maybe it's just too late.. :)